# Is this code true or not

Tags: users, user-meta

I am a beginner in coding but i have just wrote this code ,

The concept of code is :

The code adds a form with a button to each user profile. The button is captioned as Follow/ Unfollow. It updates the user meta named "following" for the user who clicked the button (follows). Then we query the user meta with the "following" value to get the list of all users who have subscribed to the authors & list out all posts of those authors.

```
<?php

 if($_GET['follow']){fun1();}

 function fun1()
 {
$fauid = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
$user_id= get_current_user_id();
$key = 'following';
$themeta = get_user_meta($user_id , $key, TRUE);
if($themeta != '') {
$user_id= get_current_user_id;
update_user_meta($user_id, 'following', $fauid); }

else {

$user_id= get_current_user_id;
add_user_meta($user_id , 'following' , $fauid , true );
update_user_meta($user_id, 'following', $fauid);
}
}

?>

<html>
    <button id="Button" name="Button" onClick='location.href="?follow=1"'>Follow Me <3 <3</button>
</html>
```

Is the code right or not?

Comment: There is a dedicated SE site for code reviewing, called [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I think this question should be better asked there

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find if a code works or not is to actually try it ;) On the face of it, it doesn't look like you are trying to handle storing the user ids in an array or any serialized way at all.

Comment: Thanks Mr Mark :) I am a Beginner in coding i have written this code after a long time of searching in Google , Can you help me please ^_^ ?